# Why swift doesn't execute main queue?

Tags: swift, macos

I have a long code and UI to refresh during execution of this code in order to inform the user.

I try to do this with `dispatchQueue` but Swift does not execute the code inside `dispatchQueue.main.async{}`. Why?

Here the beginning of my code:

```
    @IBAction func btnSave(_ sender: Any) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        profondeur = Int((self.niveauRecherche.selectedItem?.title)!)!
        //recupere l'URL saisie
        let myURLString : String = self.textUrl.stringValue
        let url = URL(string:self.textUrl.stringValue)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {                  //this code is not executed
            self.txtLog.stringValue="Veryfing first URL"
            print("ok")
        }
        //verifie la validite de l'URL de départ
        if self.checkURL(urlString: myURLString){
            UserDefaults.standard.set(myURLString, forKey: "Last_URL")
            //Ajoute l'URL de départ dans le tableau des URL
            urlArray.append([1 as AnyObject,myURLString as AnyObject])
            //recupere le nom de domaine
            let domain=url?.host
            let domainString:String=String(describing: domain!)
            let elements = domainString.components(separatedBy: ".")
            let nbElements = elements.count
            switch nbElements {
            case 3:
                nomDeDomaine=elements[1]
            default:
                nomDeDomaine=elements[0]
            }
```

Can you help me, please?
Thanks!

Comment: Is the `btnSave` action triggered at all?

Comment: What is `txtLog` and why are you running it on the main thread?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to be executed in the order you write by going to a background thread, then to the main thread, then back to a background thread, then you'll have to write your code like this:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    // Background Thread
    print("background 1")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // Run UI Updates or call completion block
        self.myLabel.text = "I have changed"
        print("Main thread")
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            print("background 2")
        }
    }
}
```

This would print:

```
background 1
Main thread
background 2
```